# Let $T: C[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]$ defined by $T(f) = f'$, all with the norm of the max.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: C[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]$ defined by $T(f) = f'$, all with the norm of the max. First of all, I think that $C^1[0,1]$ is not a banach space with the max norm. So I do not have the result that T has closed graph iff T is limited. I just have that T limited implies graph of T closed.

However, I think that T is not limited so I cannot apply that. 
Is there another theorem that can help me?

I tried doing it "by hands": let $(f_n(x),T(f_n(x)) \in graph(T)$. Suppose this is a convergent sequence with limit $(X,Y)$. If I say that X,Y belong to $C[0,1]$ and $C^1[0,1]$ respectively then I am done.

For sure, X belongs to C[0,1] because it is complete. 
However, I do not know what to do with Y. Any hints?

Comment: My gues is that you meant to write that $T$ goes from $C^1[0,1]$ into $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I agree with @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to write $T\colon C^1[0,1]\longrightarrow C[0,1]$ (otherwsise, $T$ doesn't make sense), then $T$ is not bouned. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.\end{array}$$Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$, but $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\bigl\lVert T(f_n)\bigr\rVert=1$, and therefore we don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}T(f_n)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $T: C[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]$ is not correct. Correct is $T: C^1[0,1] \to C[0,1]$. Let $D(T):=C^1[0,1]$.

Now let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $D(T)$ such that $f_n \to f \in C[0,1]$ (norm convergent) and $Tf_n \to g \in  C[0,1]$ (norm convergent).

Then the sequences $(f_n)$ and $(Tf_n)$ are uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

A theorem in Analysis now says: $f \in D(T)$ and $g=f'$.

This shows that $T$ is closed.

Observe that $T$ is not bounded !